# High heap memory consumption while Extracting SSL Certificate Info for website

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am facing high heap memory consumption issue while fetching SSL certificates(to extract issuer & buyer name) for an website in multi-threaded(50 threads) environment.

Tried setting sslmemorycachesize but didn't Work.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210985

[Heap dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPE8q.jpg)

```
URL destinationURL = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(2500);
    conn.setReadTimeout(2500);
    conn.connect();
    Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
```